# Change customer and order details on woocommerce emails

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to modify customer and order details for woocommerce emails.

I copied email-customer-details.php and email-order-details.php files to my theme template and changed them. But nothing changed!
Even when I deleted the files nothing happened and emails are sent by default!

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I should copy and change `email-addresses.php` file.